# Il papiro di laurea

Tags: word-usage, etymology, regional

Il papiro di laurea:

> - è un manifesto di dimensioni considerevoli (all'incirca 50x100 cm) nel quale il neolaureato viene messo alla berlina con aneddoti goffi sulla sua infanzia, allusioni sessuli oppure inventate su improbabili avventure erotiche protrattesi dall'asilo fino all'università. Si tratta, ovviamente,  di mera goliardia. [[Fonte](http://www.corriere.it/solferino/severgnini/07-11-19/11.spm)]

[image]

Questa tradizione goliardica sembra essere tipica delle università del nord, in particolare del nord-est. Qualcuno ne conosce l'origine? E perché si chiama "papiro"? Esiste questa tradizione anche in qualche università all'estero?

Comment: Per piacere, Josh, ricordati di mettere la fonte quando citi un brano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puoi trovare più informazioni alla voce ["Goliardia"](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goliardia) di Wikipedia.

> **Le matricole e i papiri**
>
> È più o meno a cavallo tra XIX e XX secolo, che si affermò il costume del fare la matricola e dei papiri. Gli studenti con più bolli, ossia quelli con più anni di università alle spalle, andavano a caccia dei nuovi iscritti (le matricole) per prendersi gioco di loro, riscuotere un piccolo obolo o più semplicemente farsi pagare da bere.
>
> Una volta “pelata”, alla matricola veniva rilasciata una pergamena a testimonianza dell'avvenuto pagamento, cosicché altri studenti anziani non potessero pretendere pagamenti ulteriori. Queste pergamene, riempite con disegni sconci e frasi ironiche, erano denominate papiri; i loro autori, in alcuni casi dei veri e propri artisti, erano ingaggiati dagli studenti anziani anche per immortalare le proprie gesta goliardiche in papiri di laurea, da affiggere in città una volta terminati gli studi.
>
> Questa dei papiri di laurea è una tradizione che sopravvive ancora oggi, diffusa in particolar modo tra gli studenti degli atenei di Padova, di Verona e di Venezia, oltre che di Trieste e Udine. Sempre a Padova peraltro, ma soltanto in ambiente goliardico, continua la tradizione del Papiro Matricolare, di fatto però demandata alle Accademie ed agli Ordini Goliardici.

Comment: Grazie mille per la risposta, ma tutto ciò non c'entra molto con la lingua italiana (e così la domanda stessa, a dirla tutta, a parte l'uso della parola “papiro”).